# ImportError: dlopen(...): Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, psycopg2, postgresql-12

I have been stuck on this issue for some time. After struggling to install psycpg2 on my Mac I got a friend to help me install it using this:

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip3 install psycopg2
```

I then imported psycopg2

I tried to run my db program and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postgresdemo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2 
  File "/Users/nkosana/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nkosana/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn
  Referenced from: /Users/nkosana/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib in /Users/nkosana/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

**System and versions**

MacOS Catalina (10.15.4)

psycopg2-2.8.5

Python 3.7.3

I would appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you are having:

```
Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn
  Referenced from: /Users/Lynda/pgproject/pgprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

What worked for me is adding /usr/local/lib to the PATH and create a symbolic link from my PostgreSQL/lib to /usr/local/lib

```
cd /usr/local/lib
ln -s /Users/Lynda/PostgreSQL/lib/libpq.5.12.dylib ./libpq.5.dylib
```

There is an answer that fixes this lib error and better explains why this is happening and how to fix it here [Mac OS X Lion Psycopg2: Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999105/mac-os-x-lion-psycopg2-symbol-not-found-pqbackendpid)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip install psycopg2
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236722/what-does-import-error-symbol-not-found-pqencryptpasswordconn-mean-and-how-do/58443768), worked for me. macOS Catalina version 10.15.7. Python 3.5.9

Answer (score 0):

The `ln -s` solution proposed by bgar2021 cannot work because the `.dylib` file in the OP case is expected to be in `/usr/lib`, not `/usr/local/lib`, and you cannot alter `.dylib` links or files in `/usr/lib` because of the SIP protection (and disabling the SIP protection is definitely not recommended).

In the OP case, the built-in MacOS `install_name_tool` command should work, also because the `.so` file has been put in the project folder using `venv`.

I would recommend using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), so that you have local version of the `.so` in the project folder, which is safer to alter. If you do that, you can easily solve the problem by using the built-in `install_name_tool` in MacOS to tell that the `.so` file should use the right `.dylib` file.

At that point, you can install a newer version of postgres in the project folder, for example postgresql@14, using the `pip tool` within `venv``

```
pip install postgresql@14
```

Therefore you can solve by doing something like this:

```
install_name_tool -change '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.8/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.14.dylib' '/Users/nkosana/yourproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so'
```

Please replace fake names (e.g. "yourproject") with the names you chose and double check as I may have made typos.

I hope this helps.