Django docker error with Postgres django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured
Good day.
I'm having problems comunicating django app (local) and postgres db (docker )
The db work fine with adminer.
But when I try the credentials that I use in adminer...
Boom!
...env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module

....
SETTINGS
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv("DB_ENGINE"),
        'NAME': os.getenv("DB_NAME"),
        'USER': os.getenv("DB_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
        'PORT': os.getenv("DB_PORT")
    },
    'kettle': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv("DB_ENGINE"),
        'NAME': os.getenv("DB_NAME_KETTLE"),
        'USER': os.getenv("DB_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
        'PORT': os.getenv("DB_PORT")
    }
}


ENV
DB_ENGINE='django.db.backends.postgresql'
DB_NAME='database'
DB_USER='postgres'
DB_PASSWORD='1234'
DB_HOST='db'
DB_PORT='5432'

DB_NAME_KETTLE='kettle'
ADMINER_PORT=8080

VIRTUAL ENV
asgiref==3.8.1
certifi==2024.6.2
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==42.0.8
Django==4.2.3
django-cors-headers==4.2.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
idna==3.7
psycopg==3.1.19
psycopg2==2.9.6
psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
pycparser==2.22
PyJWT==2.3.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
pytz==2024.1
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.5.0
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.1

And in my Docker, postgres is in the port 5432:5432.

What is actually in your Dockerfile?  In the output you list as "virtual env", is that the contents of a requirements.txt file that's checked into the repository?

the list is a pip freeze of the env

could you check if this works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637715/improperlyconfigurederror-loading-psycopg2-module-s-e

Sorry but no... I already tryied but nothing... But the problem is "ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module" not ImproperlyConfigured: Not found psycopg2

The problem was that I had other postgres running in my local computer.
